# Does Ceres have an exosphere similar to the Moon?

Tags: planetary-atmosphere

Thinking about the question and answers for [Does the Moon have any oxygen in its atmosphere?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/349/does-the-moon-have-any-oxygen-in-its-atmosphere) begs the question, despite being considerably smaller than the Moon and further away from the sun, does Ceres have a similar atmosphere as the Moon?

Comment: [We'll probably find out soon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_(spacecraft)#Ceres_approach).

Answer (score 3):

In general, asteroids experience the same fundamental processes as the moon: solar wind, micrometeorites  and photons from the sun are striking them and sputtering material off to form an exosphere.  So there must be some sort of exosphere, but its density and composition will vary with distance from the sun, as well as the gravity and composition of the asteroid.

A 1992 [ultraviolet study of Ceres](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1992Icar...98...54A) found $OH$ emission, consistent with escaping water, and suggesting a ice cap.

But a more [recent study](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2011AJ....142..125R) with the more sensitive [VLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_Large_Telescope)  did not detect $OH$, limiting the maximum amount of water produced  per second to $7 \times 10^{25}$ molecules per second at the time of the observation.

Comment: So equivalent to somewhat less than 2 liters liquid water per second .

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I thought it good to add an update since more information has become available.

Ceres [has indeed been confirmed by Dawn](https://www.universetoday.com/134922/confirmed-ceres-transient-atmosphere/) to have a tenuous atmosphere created by ice sublimating off the surface.